# Getting package design ready for print

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Im making a package design for my company in illustrator CS6 which im new to btw (only been using it for a couple of weeks).
Tried googling this but it has gotten me more confused :p

I have been given a template file of the package for me to make my design on.
I have placed symbols and my logo etc from other .Ai projects i have made onto the package design.

How do i prepare the final product with linked images before sending off to print?
Which resolution do i choose? 300 ppi ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello, do you have a print vendor that you will be sending this to? Generally they will give you specs on how to export the file. If everything in your design is vector based, then the ppi doesn't matter since it is vector.

Comment: There is a company that does the printing, they also sent me the template in .AI 
everything is vector yes.
Do you know how to export so i can send them the .AI file ?

Comment: they said they want .Ai or .PDF for print

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a real answer, but it is too long to be a comment.

**Warning!** Sending a file to print on a large scale, if you have no experience is a recipe for a disaster...

It is not that it is rocket science, but there are a LOT of small details that can ruin the print, and cost money.

Resolution is only one. Yes, send a 300 PPI file... except if you do not need it or need something else.

Fonts converted to paths... except if you don't. Color profiles depending on the paper or material, bleed marks, structural things on the package, the thickness of the cardboard, the orientation of the design, CMYK values of ink, overprint, transparency elements, safe zones...

A design SHOULD NOT "be prepared at the final stage before sending off to print" It needs to take into account the printing process since the beginning.

So, please talk to your provider and ask for help. Tell them exactly what you have no experience so they extra check the files.

Answer (score 0):

You've said in comments that *"everything is vector, yes"* but in your original question you mention *"linked images"* as well - when asked about whether everything is vector, what is meant is:

> "Did you draw every graphic element in this piece with a vector art tool in Illustrator, and there are **no** raster images at all?"

The reason this is a valid clarification request is that you mention in your question having placed a logo and symbols into the template `.ai` file - you make ***no*** direct mention there of placing images, *but then you mention **both** a resolution for export **and** linked images* at final export - these two statements seem to conflict.

Chances are, if they ***want*** the `.ai` file, they'll want it packaged with all linked images (the original images, at full resolution) or with those images embedded: ask them which they prefer.

If they want a print-ready PDF, ask *them* to specify the settings *they* want, as they clearly are knowledgeable about Illustrator given it's one of the filetypes they accept; if they're like most print houses, they routinely have to fix designer's file prior to being able to print successfully (from file and font linking to colourspace issues to transparency flattening, trapping and knock-outs) and so have at least one pre-press operator who is an Illustrator whizz in their use-case, hence they should be able to give3 you explicit direction as to what they need and how to get it to them.

Hope this helps.